# How to synchronize setState with another function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, synchronous, setstate

The code below is the one that I'm currently working on. What it does is to receive a file as a user input and send an axios post request, and through Spring Boot backend the passed file will be stored in a folder in my PC's C drive.

```
import React from 'react'
import { post } from 'axios';

class SimpleFileUpload extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      file:null
    }
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this)
  }

  onFormSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault() // Stop form submit
    this.fileUpload(this.state.file).then((response)=>{
      console.log(response.data);
    })
  }
  onChange(e) {
    const chosenFile = e.target.files[0];
    this.setState({file:chosenFile});
  }
  fileUpload(file){
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/report/uploadFile';
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file',file)
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }
    return  post(url, formData,config)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
        <h1>File Upload</h1>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.onChange} />
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
      </form>
   )
  }
}

export default SimpleFileUpload
```

The problem was that `setState` was performed asynchronously within the `onChange` method and and when I clicked the `Upload` button to trigger the `onFormSubmit` method, the `file` inside `this.state` was `null` and `axios.post` request failed.

I managed to have the post request successfully work by modifying the `onChange` method like below, whose idea is something close to using a callback function,

```
onChange(e) {
  const chosenFile = e.target.files[0];
  this.setState({file:chosenFile});

  this.fileUpload(chosenFile).then((response)=>{
    console.log(response.data);
  })  
}
```

but the problem with this way is that the post request gets sent even without clicking the `Upload` button.

I tried to wrap the `setState` with an `await` feature by adding the two methods below,

```
setStateSynchronous(stateUpdate){
  return new Promise(
    this.setState({file:stateUpdate})
  )
}

async callSynchSetState(stateUpdate){
  await this.setStateSynchronous(stateUpdate);
}
```

and mofified the `onChange` method like below, but it didn't work.

```
onChange(e) {
  const chosenFile = e.target.files[0];
  //this.setState({file:chosenFile});
  this.callSynchSetState(chosenFile);
    
  /*this.fileUpload(chosenFile).then((response)=>{
    console.log(response.data);
  })  */
}
```

Any idea on how to send the chosen file only if the `Upload` button is clicked?

Comment: Just use `await` in front of `setState` or use the callback. That's easier.

Comment: The problem with using ```await``` in front of ```setState``` is that I get an error like ```Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function```. Callback function like way is the one that I showed in my original post, but like I mentioned the problem with that is that a post request is sent even without pressing the ```Upload``` button. What I want to do (also already written in the original post) is, to let the user send a post request only if the ```Upload``` button is pressed.

Comment: So a user is able to somehow select a file and click the submit button all within the same render cycle such that the state update hasn't occurred yet for the submit handler? Is that what I'm understanding?

Comment: No, a user does't have time to click the submit button after choosing a file. A user is able to select a file, but even before clicking a submit button the file is sent via the post request. What I want to do is to have a post request sent only if the submit button is pressed.

Comment: That is what your initial code up top looks to be doing, so are you saying the input's `onChange` is triggering the form to submit? Or something else is happening?

Comment: @Sean2014 Make the upload button disabled based on the `this.state.file` or a new state which is comfortable for you.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, ```onChange``` is the one causing the submit, and it doesn't give time for the submit button to be pressed, and that's the problem.

Comment: @LazyCoder I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. I need to see a piece of code that corresponds to what you're saying. Without that it's quite hard to visualize what you are talking about.

Comment: Is the issue that a user is entering text into the input *and then* pressing the enter key at the end? *That* sometimes can submit the form, otherwise I don't any path through your code posted up top how the `onChange` handler could ever submit the form. In this scenario you'll want to also `event.preventDefault()` the event object in the change handler. You want to do this pretty much *any time* you're interacting with a form in react.

Comment: No, in the input field there is just a button to choose a file and it's impossible to enter text. Actually the problem has been solved thanks to @furitetepporaa's post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt to wrap the `setState` is not completely wrong. You just needed to write more succinctly.

Instead of

```
setStateSynchronous(stateUpdate){
  return new Promise(
    this.setState({file:stateUpdate})
  )
}

async callSynchSetState(stateUpdate){
  await this.setStateSynchronous(stateUpdate);
}
```

, just wrap the `setState` like so

```
async awaitSetState(stateUpdate){
    await this.setState({file:stateUpdate})
}
```

, and then just call that method in `onChange` method like so

```
onChange(e) {
  const chosenFile = e.target.files[0];
  this.awaitSetState(chosenFile);
}
```

Comment: That solved the problem! I really appreciate an answer with some pieces of code like this :)